# vue bootstrap pagination for multiple tables in a page

Tags: datatable, pagination, bootstrap-vue, nuxtjs3

I have multiple bootstrap tables in a page. The same json data is looped and displaying as different datatables with saperation of a accordion. When i tried to paginate it, only issue with next page. when we click next page, all tables are moving to next page.

````
                ```
         <b-collapse
          :id="`accordion-${user.id}`"
          visible
          accordion="my-accordion"
          role="tabpanel"
        >
          <b-card-body
            v-for="propertyManagement in user.property_managements"
            :key="propertyManagement.id"
          >
            <p class="card-title-desc">
              <b>{{ $t('Building') }} : </b
              >{{ propertyManagement.building_name }}
            </p>
            <b-card-text>
              <div class="table-responsive mb-0">
                <b-table
                  :items="propertyManagement.new_notifications"
                  :fields="fields"
                  :per-page="perPage"
                  :current-page="currentPage"
                  :id="'notification-table' + propertyManagement.id"
                  responsive="sm"
                  :busy="isBusy"
                >
                ....
                </b-table>
                <b-pagination
                        v-model="currentPage"
                        :total-rows="propertyManagement.new_notifications.length"
                        :per-page="perPage"
                        :aria-controls="'notification-table' + propertyManagement.id"
                        pills>
                </b-pagination>```
````

so, here only one b-table is used and "propertyManagement.new_notifications" date is looped for showing multiple datatables saperated by accordian.
currentPage is defined as 1 initially

I have used b-pagination like above code, everything works fine except the next page since next page is reflected in all datatables.

Is there any way to only show next page of selected and remaining all set to default first page?